# Loop While dentro do Ireport

Tags: java, ireport, jasper-reports, jasper

Gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de inserir loop dentro do ireport ?
Tenho um relatório em FPDF e dentro do mesmo existe dois loop while e gostaria de refazer esse relatório utilizando o ireport .

Comment: Acredito que você pode usar subreports para isso...

Comment: ok, dentro do relatorio em FPDF existe 2 while e 4 querys, no caso, teria que criar 4 subRelatórios referenciando essas querys querys ?

Comment: Cara.... acredito que sim, não trabelhei muito ainda com ireport, talvez tenha alguma solução melhor..

Comment: alguem teria um exemplo de utilizando while dentro do ireport ?

Comment: @hulckb Depende muito do que você quer. Geralmente o primeiro loop é o próprio relatório e se houver loops internos aí sim vira um subreport. Mas subreports somente são necessários caso haja uma hierarquia de dados, onde o loop mais externo gera um cabeçalho com os dados e o loop interno vários registros de detalhe. Caso os vários loops componham um conjunto homogêneo de dados, você pode simplesmente adicionar tudo numa lista só e passar para o relatório. Além disso há duas formas principais de trabalhar com relatórios Jasper: via query ou passando listas de dados com objetos.

Comment: Seria interessante você postar a estrutura que deseja para o relatório.